# How to change details on Slack via SlackAPI and PSSlack Module

Tags: powershell, slack, slack-api

I've been looking into creating a script for changing user's emails through the use of the slack API. I've gone through the process of setting up an application bot and adding it within the server as well as granting the needed permissions via Oauth. The script current looks like the following:

```
$SlackToken = "xoxp"
$SlackAllUsers = Send-SlackApi -Token $SlackToken -Method 'users.list' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Members'
$SlackAllUsers = $SlackAllUsers | Where-Object { $_.is_bot -eq $false -and $_.is_restricted -eq $false }
$UserEmail = 'x'
$SlackUserID = $SlackAllUsers | Where-Object { $_.Profile.Email -eq $UserEmail } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'ID'
$SlackUserID
$UserEmailNew = 'y'
Send-SlackApi -Token $SlackToken -Method 'users.profile.set' -Body `
@{
    user = $SlackUserID
    profile = @{
        email = $UserEmailNew
    }
}
```

Effectively it makes use of the `users.list` method to grab all users within the specific channel and then filters these users to remove accounts that aren't relevant. I'm attempting to use `users.profile.set` to apply changes here, this is where I'm running into issues, I do not know why but this is resulting in the following error:

```
Parse-SlackError : Unknown error invalid_profile received from Slack API.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSSlack\1.0.5\Public\Send-SlackAPI.ps1:115 char:21
```

When testing `$SlackUserID` I can see I'm correctly grabbing the ID specific to who I'm attempting to change and edit. Having read through the documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set) on `users.profile.set` it appears this is the only method for actually applying changes through the use of the API. Important to note, within my environment we not using an enterprise environment meaning I do not have access to the `admin.*` Oauth permissions so cannot approach this issue with that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the main issue I was having was specifically the part handling the changing request sent via the API token. The start and middle sections do work, I confirmed this by testing the email and the ID grabbing and the pipe the correct details. The changing part simple needs to read as

```
Send-SlackApi -Token $SlackToken -Method 'users.profile.set' -Body `
@{
    user = $SlackUserID
    profile = @{
        email = $UserEmailNew
    } | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

Looking back this seems obvious, if you're piping API calls which are based on JSON it means you need to add `ConvertTo-Json` for it to be interpreted correctly.